# How to check if a table within a DataSet exists

Tags: c#

I'm populating a dataset with several tables.  But they may not always have rows.

So I want to check if a given table exists before trying to access it (and cause an exception)

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
```

// populate the dataset

I have tried the following options but both throw an exception regarding a non existent table.  How do I check for this without erroring out.

option 1.

```
if(ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0)
```

option 2

```
if(ds.Tables[1] != null)
```

Comment: if (ds.Tables.Count >= 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the tables with names and using the table name to check if a table exists:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
var table = ds.Tables.Add();
table.TableName = "some_name";

if (ds.Tables.Contains("some_name")) {
    // do your logic...
    var theTable = ds.Tables["some_name"];
    if (table.Rows.Count == 0) {
    }
}
```

By using table names, your code will look cleaner and more readable.

If you just want to iterate all tables you could just:

```
foreach (DataTable tbl in ds.Tables)
{
    if (tbl.Rows.Count > 0) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Accessing rows of a non existent table was erroring out.   This worked though!

if(Tables.Count  > 1)

Comment: @John if you access Table[1] you're accessing the second table because the collection of tables are 0-index based. You could iterate with a `for each` which gives you clearer code, but that's just a style preference. I'm glad it's working for you now.